# Not getting complete URL parameters

Tags: 8, uri

My url is `node/3?filter-value=67&filter-value=80` and when i try to do this code:

```
$param = \Drupal::request()->query->all();`

$param['filter-value']
```

It shows the value `80` only. I want to get both of them.

Comment: This is a question about PHP in general, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353379/how-to-get-multiple-parameters-with-same-name-from-a-url-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ll need to use array notation in the URL:

> node/3?filter-value[]=67&filter-value[]=80

Then `get(‘filter-value’)` will return an array with both values.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string for more information.

Answer (score 3):

if you don't want to change the structure of your url.

you can use [Explode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

I have made a helper function try it out:

```
function getParamsOfUrlWithSameKey(){
  $current_uri = \Drupal::request()->getRequestUri();
  $items = explode('?', $current_uri);
  $res_param = [];
  if (isset($items[1])) {
    $params = explode('&', $items[1]);
    foreach ($params as $param) {
      $param_value = explode('=', $param);
      $key = $param_value[0];
      $value = $param_value[1];
      $res_param[$key][] = $value;
    }
  }
  return $res_param;
}
```

The return of this function will be something like:

```
array:1 [▼
   "filter-value" => array:2 [▼
     0 => "67"
     1 => "80"
   ]
 ]
```